# What am I supposed to do with bower_components folder?

Tags: node.js, bower

Should I just host it? With all the sources and read-me's? Or should my build scripts selectively copy components from it into my `/scripts` folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use grunt or gulp and concatenate all the js files you want from bower_components. And just have a single include in your html.  You don't need everything in the folders typically the files you want is the same name as the component. Sometimes located in a dist folder. I Would recommend not using minified while developing, because then it may be harder to debug

Answer (score 2):

Are you use `Grunt`? If yes, it has `[grunt-bower-task][1]` which is able to selectively move the main required `bower_components` that configured in `bower.json` to your destination, so your `dist` folder, or whatever it called will be clean.

I suggest to use `[Yeoman][2]` instead, it's included `Yo` for scaffolding, `bower` for front end package management, and `grunt` for task runner. With pre-configured `Gruntfile.js` that most of Yeoman's generator does, it able to package your project to `production mode` that usually `minified` and/ or `uglified` your scripts, stylesheet, and also template/ *.html files.